# How do we solve the equation $\sinh^{-1}(x) + \cosh^{-1}(x+2) = 0$?

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

I've recently started learning hyperbolic functions and inverse hyperbolic functions, and I came across this equation involving inverse hyperbolic functions. I tried to solve it numerically (I got x=-0.747), but how would you solve it analytically? I don't know how to type in latex so please forgive me.

$$\sinh^{-1}(x) + \cosh^{-1}(x+2) = 0$$

Comment: Have you considered arithmetic manipulations, such as moving one term or the other to the opposite side of the equation, taking $\sinh$ or $\cosh$ of both sides, etc.?  Where did you encounter the listed problem?

Comment: $-0.747$ seems awfully close to  negative simple fraction, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

$$\sinh^{-1}(x)=-\cosh^{-1}(x+2)$$

Apply $\cosh^2(x)$ on both sides

$$\cosh^2(\sinh^{-1}(x))=\cosh^2(-\cosh^{-1}(x+2))=(x+2)^2$$

since $\cosh$ is even. Since $\cosh^2(x)=1+\sinh^2(x)$ we have on the LHS

$$\cosh^2(\sinh^{-1}(x))=1+\sinh^2(\sinh^{-1}(x))=1+x^2$$

So $$1+x^2=(x+2)^2$$
$$ 1+x^2=x^2+4x+4$$
$$-3=4x$$
and finally $$x=-\frac{3}{4}$$

Comment: Thank you very much, jjagmath. I tried to cosh both sides of the equation but didn't get very far so proceed to do it numerically. Now I realise I should have cosh^2 both sides of the equation.

Comment: @Abiessu, I saw this problem online on CIMT hyperbolic functions (google that) click the pdf link. The question is on Exercise 2D, question 4.

Answer (score -1):

HINTS:

Drawing circular and hyperbolic function triangles for inverse functions may be helpful:

[image]

Identities

$$ \cosh^2 x - \sinh ^2 x = 1 $$

$$ \cosh (a +b)= \cosh a \cosh b + \sinh a \sinh b $$

Given equation

$$ \cosh^{-1}\sqrt{1+x^2} + \cosh^{-1}(x+2) =0 $$

Take cosh both sides

$$\sqrt{1+x^2}(x+2) + ..... =1 $$

Can you take it forward?

Another easier way:

$$ \sinh^{-1 }(-x) =  \cosh^{-1}(x+2)$$

$$ \cosh^{-1}\sqrt{1+x^2}=  \cosh^{-1}(x+2) \to $$

Take cosh both sides and simplify algebra.

$$ 1+x^2 = x^2+4 x +4 ; 4x+3=0 \;; x=-\frac34. $$

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2+1}=x+2$ does not give $x^2-x-1=0$. You have to equate $x^2+1$ with $(x+2)^{\color{blue}{2}}$.

Comment: Thanks.  Error in last  algebraic step corrected.